# Shortest code to create an error that isn't a NameError or SyntaxError

Tags: python, interpreter

In Python, many statements can cause errors, but I would like to know what are the simplest statements that can cause an Error **except** for `NameError` and `SyntaxError` and their subclasses such as `IdentationError`

Using the interactive Python shell, I have tried using single characters in statements but they are all `NameError`s or `SyntaxError`s, and I tried two characters, it is also the same, so I wonder if there are any possibilities to cause other types of errors by using 3 or fewer characters in Python. if this is impossible, then why so?

Comment: This might almost be better posted in codegolf.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the shortest one would be a three-character `ZeroDivisionError`. Like this:

```
1/0
```

Almost everything that isn't a `NameError` or `SyntaxError` is going to need some kind of operator, which will bump you up to three characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear if you are looking for the absolute shortest code to cause an error, or if you are looking for several short examples that cause a variety of different errors.

For the later, add these two to your list:

```
x, = 5 # TypeError
```

and

```
x, y = 5, # ValueError
```

and

```
x, = [] # ValueError
```

Not quite as short as Michael M's answer, but still short.

Comment: You can get the same error with just `x,= 5` - because y not?

Answer (score 0):

only available in the interpreter

nothing and `^C`

```py
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

bitwise negation of a float raises `TypeError` in 3 characters

```py
>>> ~.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cause a `TypeError` by trying to negate a tuple, for example:

```
>>> -()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'
```